# Can't use www.google.com NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID SSL certificate is not valid

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, certificate

I build a new PC and trying to enjoy it but for some reason I can not reach google. If I try to go https://www.google.com/ I am getting error as : [image]

----But when I click on the certificates it says that certificate is ok:

[image]

If I use https://www.google.com.tr/ instead of https://www.google.com/ it works. (tr stands for Turkey). But not the other vise:

[image]

This problem is not only on Chrome. Every other browser have same error on this computer.
I tried so many things.

-I checked if windows time is correct,

-I cleared SSL certificate state,

-I  changed proxysettinperuser on Regedit.

(Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings)

[image]

This is not only effecting my google search, it is also hinders me to upload a youtube video:

[image]

**I have another computer on same network an that one have no problem.** I do not know what to do. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you got man-in-the-middled. There are many possible explanations.

Comment: same case with me... waiting for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delete my ssl certificate from my default browser for google.com.sg, and then boom i can access google.com again.
[image]

Comment: Yes you are right, deleting other certificates but google.com fix my problem too. Thanks

Comment: but it re install certificate every time. I need to delete every time.

Comment: it different with my case, sorry i dont know how to solve it...